# Changing a content fields in Drupal 7 using php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm having issues creating a php function that gives me a result based on the contents of other fields. It in turn needs to store the result in a different field.

EG.
User has 3 fields in a content type called 'math_addition'

```
field_number_1
field_number_2
field_answer
```

The php function must read the value the user enters in `field_number_1` and `field_number_2` and add them together. Then it sends the results to `field_answer`.

I can't seem to manage to interact with the fields in Drupal. I just need to know how to get the field values, and then how to change them.

Comment: I have managed to use the rules module to output the results from any calculations, but I still can't manage to be able to use the fields in the calculations.

Comment: You should also try with calculated field module

Answer (score 0):

If you want create a php function - it' simple.
You must load your entity, modify field value and save back to the database.
for exmaple, for some node object

```
$node = node_load(100500); // node nid as parameter
$node->field_answer[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 123456; // set new value
node_save($node);
```

You can learn more about node or user objects structure with the devel module. Just install it and go to the "devel" tab on corresponding pages (user/% and node/%).